# Selenium to Ranorex

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, ranorex

For the past few months, I have been automating using Selenium. We are planning to move to Ranorex. Is there a way to move my Selenium scripts (in Java) to Ranorex?

I don't want to execute the Selenium scripts from Ranorex using the connector from Ranorex IDE, but want to port the code, so I don't have to maintain scripts in Selenium and Ranorex.

Any suggestions/options will be great…

Comment: Since a link is never really an answer I make this comment: Look at this link for the answer: https://www.ranorex.com/ranorex-vs-selenium.html

Comment: A link can be an answer as long as there is a description of the contents and relevant quote.

Answer (score 2):

How/if you can do this is highly dependent on the type of application you are testing, the way your test framework is structured, etc..

Worded as it is, your question doesn't give me enough information to give you an answer. If, however, you are asking if there is some automated way to translate a Selenium script to a Ranorex Script, then no, there really isn't.

Going forward, I recommend go onto the Ranorex forum and ask for specific advice regarding whatever bottlenecks you encounter. It's a pretty active community and some very knowledgeable people are regulars there.

Link: http://www.ranorex.com/forum/

Comment: Thanks John. I will run through the Ranorex forum to get more information.

Comment: As Ranorex and Selenium themselves and the logic behind them are very different there is no automatic way to do this. The way both achive something similar is different and the devloped custom methods don't really match. But yeah I would suggest as well to take a look at the Ranorex forum and if you have any questions just post a topic there.

Comment: @Raj You're welcome. If you have time, please select my answer to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

@Raj Even there is some port for Java code to C#, there are lots of bottlenecks for which you may not do this automatically.

1. There is no such counterpart of Selenium in Ranorex
2. You need your classes in Recording module format.
3. If you do not maintain a static repo file, you cannot match with Ranorex repo.

However, as [John_The_Schnauzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6667911/john-the-schnauzer), you always can get some expert feedback from their forums.

Best of luck!